# Difference between bin and exe when creating a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm creating a gem for the first time and I'm a bit confused by the `bin/` and `exe/` directories.
I've added an executable to `spec.executables` with:

```
spec.bindir        = "exe"
spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
```

but when I `gem build` it it asks me for a "binary" in both `bin/` and `exe/` and I'm very confused because I can't really understand the difference between the 2.
I solved the problem by copying the executable in `bin/` into `exe/` and everything works, but looks somewhat weird and suboptimal.
Can anybody explain?

Comment: Use `bin` everywhere. `exe` is produced by a weird bundler template.

Answer (score 2):

`bin/` is for *development* executables and will not be included in the built gem.

`exe/` is for *end user* executables and will be included in the built gem, and thus copied to the user's `bin/` in their `PATH`.

Ref: https://bundler.io/blog/2015/03/20/moving-bins-to-exe.html

> This is a new convention. The current practice of both specifying `bin/` as the `executables` directory and where we put binstubs and other development-only executables such as `bin/rail`s or `bin/setup`, meant that Bundler-generated gems with executables were quite likely to have these development executables included in the built gem, and then installed along with the gem.
>
> Rather than make the gemspec template more restrictive by only specifying one executable in `bin/` as an `executable`, the Bundler team has chosen to use a different directory, `exe/`, as the `executables` directory in the template.

The post indicates that the reason for the `exe/` directory is to allow blanket add all files in there to the user's `bin` or `PATH`.

You can still use the `bin/` directory and manually specify the user executables.

```rb
  spec.bindir        = 'bin'
  spec.executables   = 'new_gem'
```